# DEVC++ Makefil.win has changed. Reload from disk? ERROR

Tags: c++, makefile, linker-errors, dev-c++

I just finished downloading the Dev C++ and my instructor told me follow his instructions (and so i did) but when i compile and run it it shows this error. idk how to fix it so can you help me?

I have downloaded it in my Dell Latitude 3410 using Windows 10 and run it on 64 bit. I also downloaded freeglut since it is instructed by the instructor.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCBrN.jpg)

I want to quickly fix this since my instructor expects us to do all the tasks immediately.

Comment: I believe the "skipping incompatible ..." messages are you are mixing 32 and 64 bit with the libraries you installed at `D:/freeglut/lib`

Comment: ***Makefil.win has changed. Reload from disk?*** Is not an error.